# Raspberry Pi Bluetooth MAC address storage

Tags: bluetooth

I'm looking at using a Raspberry Pi 4B for some Bluetooth testing. It appears to use the same CYW43455 chipset as the 3B, with support for reprogramming of the Bluetooth MAC address, which would be useful for simulating access from different devices.

A potential problem with this is that some flash/EEPROM memories have very limited endurance and will fail after a small number of erase/write cycles. Does anyone know how this information is stored, and specifically what kind of endurance the storage has?

Comment: "flash/EEPROM memories have very limited endurance and will fail after a small number of erase/write cycles" - This is wrong. A typical EEPROM chip can be erased tens or hundreds of thousands of times before it "fails", and "failure" means the data retention time will drop to less than 2..10 years.

Comment: You changed the meaning of the sentence with selective quoting. I've seen ratings as low as 50 write/erase cycles. Also, the failure mode is most often that bits no longer erase reliably, resulting in corrupted data. In this case, the BT hardware was probably not designed with constant MAC address changes in mind, and there's no guarantee that it was placed in a high-endurance storage.