# Pi 4 change Bluetooth MAC adress

Tags: pi-4, bluetooth, reset

I want to change the bluetooth mac address of the builtin wifi/bluetooth chip, but all my attempts have been futile despite multiple sources (including the commands) implying it to be possible. See e.g. [this question about how often it can be done](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/107525/raspberry-pi-bluetooth-mac-address-storage).

A few notes on what exactly i want/need:

- I need to change the vendor bytes to some known "authentic" ones.
- both temporary and permanent change would suffice
- spoofing is also ok, as long as other devices don't notice
- other features beyond bluetooth are expendable, say if e.g. the Wifi misbehaves
- I don't care about specific versions of firmware/packages
- I currently use `bluetoothctl show` to view the current MAC if that matters

What I tried (and didnt't work yet):

From [this post by infineon](https://community.cypress.com/t5/Wi-Fi-Bluetooth-for-Linux/How-to-change-Bluetooth-MAC-address-on-Raspberry-Pi-4/m-p/179476):
I tried both what worked for the asker:

```
# hcitool cmd 0x3f 0x001 0x01 0x23 0x45 0x67 0x89 0xab
< HCI Command: ogf 0c3f, ocf 0x001, plen 6
  01 23 45 67 89 ab
> HCI Event: 0x0e plen 4
  01 01 FC 00
```

and what didnt:

```
# sudo bdaddr -i hci0 01:23:45:67:89:ab
Manufacturer:   Cypress Semiconductor Corporation (305)
Device address: DC:A6:32:16:71:D4
New BD address: 01:23:45:67:89:ab

Address changed - Reset device now
```

And I presume both work but I need to powercycle, presumably the bluetooth? How would I do that. I tried a `shutdown -r` but that just reset the address back to stock. Do I have toggle some GPIO? send more magic numbers via `hcitool cmd`?

Edit: after comments I tried `bthelper hci0` to no avail and looking into the sourcethe command it calls `hciconfig hci0 reset` also has no effect.

the `btmgmt` also has commands to change mac, but these always fail. I couldn't find anything related to reset, but there are undocumented opcodes.

Any tipps are also appreciated.

Used versions (latest as of 17.04.2021):

- bluetoothd: 5.50
- bluetoothctl: 5.50
- pi-bluetooth: 0.1.15
- cypress firmware: brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio
- raspi firmware: 3. Sep 2020
- kernel: 5.10.17-v7l+

Comment: running `sudo bthelper hci0` seems to do exactly what you want

Comment: You don't say if you want to change the classic address or change a BLE address. You might want to also look at `btmgmt` tool. More information at: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/mgmt-api.txt#n2248 and https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/mgmt-api.txt#n1710

Comment: `bthelper hci0` does something, but also reports `BDADDR already set`, `btmgmt` has a set address command, but always prints "rejected". Edit: and neither of both change the address according to `bluetoothctl` or my laptop scanning.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.
TLDR: (run everyhting as root, you won't get permission errors if you don't but it won't work)

After every reboot (yes the bytes in reverse)

```
hcitool cmd 0x3f 0x001 0xab 0x89 0x67 0x45 0x23 0x01
```

and every time you want to change it:

```
bdaddr -i hci0 01:23:45:67:89:ab
hciconfig hci0 reset
systemctl restart bluetooth.service
```

Source: https://scribles.net/changing-a-bluetooth-device-address-on-raspberry-pi/, but don't use the suggested version of `bdaddr` use the one supplied with the raspi4

The problem apparently was that everything in the stack caches the MAC and you have to reset the entire stack in the *correct* order else it will retain the old one. Also you *have* to use these BT commands, as others offering the same funcionallity seem to not work (e.g. `btaddr -r`).

Also linux uses the mac as an alias for the device and some tools get confused as to what is going on when it changes. Thats why `hciconfig` didn't report the change earlier.

Edit: The extra step after reboot